# Why index out of range?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

i'm trying to webscrape some products and i'm getting this error whenever i'm enter the code

```
import bs4, requests

def getFravegaPrice(productUrl):
    res = requests.get(productUrl)
    res.raise_for_status ()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    elems = soup.select('#wrapper > div.border-main > div > div > div.col-md-9.col-sm-9.col-xs-12 > div:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(7) > div')
    return elems[0].text
    
price = getFravegaPrice('https://compragamer.com/index.php?seccion=3&cate=62&nro_max=50')
print ('The price is ' + price)
```

Comment: make sure `elems` has elements when you invoke `elems[0].txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested, the selector you are using is incorrect, so `elems` is empty. Here is an alternative to scrape the price of an item.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res = requests.get('https://compragamer.com/index.php?seccion=3&cate=62&nro_max=50')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
item_name = "" #Enter item name you are scraping here
for item in soup.find_all("a"):
    if item_name == item.text.strip():
        price = item.parent.parent.find("span", {"class": "products__price-new"}).text.strip()
```

Comment: wow, thank you!, this actually solved all, for other pages just need to change the requests.get right?

Comment: You're welcome. This code won't work for a different website, as another website is structured differently. You will need to create a different scraper for each website you want to scrape.

Comment: oh, yeah, i just want to scrap that website in particular so i dont think it's a problem, i'm amazed anyways.

Comment: If you just want to scrape this website, chances are that you can reuse this code. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The operation `soup.select` with that selector outputs an empty `list`, so there is no `elems[0]`.

Comment: so i need to use a diferent selector? or is a thing of the page?

Comment: yes, the selector `'#wrapper > div.border-main > div > div > div.col-md-9.col-sm-9.col-xs-12 > div:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(7) > div'` didn't match with anything on the page, u need a correct selector.

Comment: hmm, strange, becuase i inspected the price and that was the selector of the page, well, thank you c: